# tkinter button image loses transparency when pressed

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have button widgets with different background colors, and transparent gif images. My problem is that when I press the button, the transparency is lost briefly which looks dumb.

During a button press, spots in the gif image that are supposed to be same colored as the button background are in DefaultBackground color instead.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Here's a very simple example of a button widget I have, it is applied to a frame

```
Button(frame, image=img, bg="#ff73c8")
```

A very simple pink button held down, changes color

[image]

the image I used in my example, has transparent background

[image]

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: Do you have a parameter for command?

Comment: Yes but removing it doesn't fix my problem. I just decided to leave it out from the example as it is unimportant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a button is pressed it becomes active, which is different from its ordinary state, so you need to specify the parameter `activebackground`:

```
Button(r, image=i, bg="#ff73c8", activebackground="#ff73c8")
```

See more on button states [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm).